# eigen3 with libfmt >= 9.0

Tags: eigen, eigen3, fmt

I used to be able to pass Eigen3 arrays/matrices to spdlog, which internally uses libfmt. Starting with libfmt 9.0.0, these types are no longer formatted by libfmt without further code.

Custom types are supported in fmt by specializing `fmt::formatter<T>` for the type; [fmt9 documentation](https://fmt.dev/9.0.0/api.html#std-ostream-support) further explains that deriving this specialization from `ostream_formatter` will make use of existing `operator<<`, which Eigen classes conveniently provide.

Eigen [uses the CRTP inheritance](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicClassHierarchy.html) and I will specialize for all `Eigen::DenseBase<T>` types like this:

```cpp
#include<fmt/ostream.h>
#include<eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include<iostream>

template <typename T> struct fmt::formatter<T,std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Eigen::DenseBase<T>,T>>>: ostream_formatter {};

int main(){
    Eigen::Array3f a(1,2,3);
    std::cout<<fmt::format("{}",a)<<std::endl;
}
```

Since I am posting, it is already clear this did not go well:

```
In file included from /usr/include/fmt/format.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/fmt/ostream.h:18,
                 from /tmp/aa.cpp:1:
/usr/include/fmt/core.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr fmt::v9::detail::value<Context> fmt::v9::detail::make_value(T&&) [with Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; T = Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1>&]’:
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1771:29:   required from ‘constexpr fmt::v9::detail::value<Context> fmt::v9::detail::make_arg(T&&) [with bool IS_PACKED = true; Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; fmt::v9::detail::type <anonymous> = fmt::v9::detail::type::custom_type; T = Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1>&; typename std::enable_if<IS_PACKED, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]’
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1895:77:   required from ‘constexpr fmt::v9::format_arg_store<Context, Args>::format_arg_store(T&& ...) [with T = {Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&}; Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; Args = {Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>}]’
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1912:31:   required from ‘constexpr fmt::v9::format_arg_store<Context, typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Args>::type>::type ...> fmt::v9::make_format_args(Args&& ...) [with Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; Args = {Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&}]’
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:3184:44:   required from ‘std::string fmt::v9::format(fmt::v9::format_string<T ...>, T&& ...) [with T = {Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; fmt::v9::format_string<T ...> = fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char, Eigen::Array<float, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&>]’
/tmp/aa.cpp:7:24:   required from here
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1751:7: error: static assertion failed: Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt
 1751 |       formattable,
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/fmt/core.h:1751:7: note: ‘formattable’ evaluates to false
```

Can I get some explanation how to do this correctly? I would like to both understand what's going c++-wise here and also have a working solution based on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `formatter` takes a character (code unit) type as a second template parameter and you pass `void` there via `enable_if_t` which cannot possibly work. The fix is to pass `char` or another code unit type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<
  T,
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_base_of_v<Eigen::DenseBase<T>, T>,
    char>> : ostream_formatter {};
//  ^ code unit type
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/x1Tr3MPYY

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Now, I have this in headers in two compilation units (they are first compiled into static libs, then linked with the main program - perhaps I need to change that), violating ODR when linking (multiple definition). Is there a quick fix? I will put it as a separate question if non-trivial.

Comment: I put the ODR as a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757587/ .

Answer (score 6):

If you have c++20 you could also use a concept, which prevents getting into this SFINAE / void trap:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    requires std::is_base_of_v<Eigen::DenseBase<T>, T>
struct fmt::formatter<T> : ostream_formatter {};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WGG77vGEr

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Comment: I like this solution, but for everybody using MSVC it may be interesting to know that it made compile-time of my project (which isn't doing much I/O, and mostly prints the same few Eigen types) blow up by roughly 10% comparted to the `std::enable_if` version.

Comment: @vitaut feeling honored by the tweet. I think the message is that MSVC's `enable_if` implementation is really good ...

Comment: That's the spirit =D

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions for `Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>` work well for most of the cases, but I found they don't cover to the formatted `Eigen::WithFormat<ExpressionType>` output from `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::format()`.

For that you will need to add

```cpp
template <typename T> struct fmt::formatter<Eigen::WithFormat<T>> : ostream_formatter {};
```

Also deserving of a mention, in case the correct solutions don't quite want to work, is the quick and dirty option of setting the `FMT_DEPRECATED_OSTREAM` define, which restores the pre-v9 behavior.