# Implicit class instantiations translation units: multiple definition when linking

Tags: c++, templates, linkage, class-template

I have two static libraries linked in a resulting executable. Both of them identically define the class template [`fmt::formatter`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#std-ostream-support)`<shatred_ptr<T>,char>` template for formatting `shared_ptr<T>` (for logging purposes). The definitions are identical in each library and [look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73748856):

```cpp
#include<fmt/ostream.h>
template <typename T> struct fmt::formatter<std::shared_ptr<T>,char>: ostream_formatter {};
```

The template is implicitly instantiated for many different `T`s.

When the executable is being linked, I get complains about multiple definition of the

```
error: redefinition of ‘struct fmt::v9::formatter<std::shared_ptr<_Tp>, char>’
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler to merge the definitions, which are token-to-token identical? I tried various things like putting `inline`, `extern`, `__attribute__((visibility,"hidden"))` to various places; using "object" library (as CMake calls it — I assume it meas just object archive) instead of static and others.

I will appreciate an explanation of this (yet another) c++ corner; and a minimally-invasive solution.

Comment: I think the static library may be the problem here (instead of translation unit). which doesn't specified in c++ standard afaict.

Comment: @DavisHerring: if you mean `: ostream_formatter {}`, that is correct, it is the parent class of the template. The code compiles, it is a copy&paste.

Comment: @eudoxos: Right, sorry—without whitespace in front I just didn’t think of that!

Comment: (Let me try again and hopefully be less wrong.)  Are you sure this is a **linking** error?  That looks like a compilation error from seeing both copies of that declaration in different header files.

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right!! Thank you so much. I wrote an answer, so please at least accept my virtual moral credit going to you (or write na anwer yourself and I will upvote & accept it).

Answer (score 2):

Crediting @DavisHerring for noticing that the error was compile-time, not link-time (there were some semi-related linking errors before and I did not check this case again carefully). Thus I could guard the two identical definitions via a macro, as e.g. here, which fixed the case where headers from both libs were included from the main program.

```cpp
#include<fmt/ostream.h>
#ifndef FMT_EIGEN_SHARED_PTR_FORMATTER
    #define FMT_EIGEN_SHARED_PTR_FORMATTER
    template <typename T> struct fmt::formatter<std::shared_ptr<T>,char>: ostream_formatter {};
#endif
```